# how to return a substring of a fixed length out of a string?

Tags: sql, substring

I have a field named **Remarks** which looks like the following:

```
    My voter card number is ABC123456789
    VOter card ID is vbv147258369
    bnl478512369
```

I want to get only the substrings of a given length from all the rows in this field.  For the above input, and the substring length of 12, the output should be

```
ABC123456789
vbv147258369
bnl478512369
```

Note that the length of the substring is fixed i.e. 12

Comment: what is your programming language

Comment: 'ABC123456789' size is 12 ?  is its correct output you want

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer...)

Comment: I have edited the code to state the substring as length 12 instead of 10, consistent with @Mr. Bhosale's comment.  I have also attempted to clarify the question. Please verify it is consistent with your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
DECLARE @CONTENT TABLE(REMARK VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @CONTENT VALUES('My voter card number is ABC123456789');
INSERT INTO @CONTENT VALUES('VOter card ID is vbv147258369');
INSERT INTO @CONTENT VALUES('bnl478512369');

SELECT CASE charindex(' ',REMARK)
    WHEN 0 THEN REMARK  
    ELSE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REMARK),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(REMARK))))
END as REMARK FROM @CONTENT
```

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
select Remarks,SUBSTRING(Remarks,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Remarks)-3,LEN(Remarks))
FROM #TableName
```

> Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since no RDBMS product is mentioned, I will stick to answer with algorithm. You need to use `RIGHT` function and extract last 12 characters from String. In case of MSSQL `RIGHT` function is available, in case of Oracle and other products, you can get desired output by using combination of `substring` function and `length` function.

Assuming substring function has signature like `substring(input,start_poistion, no_of_characters)`, the way to extract right most 12 character is

`substring(input_string, length(input_string)-12,12)`

If this does not meet your requirements, the alternate solution is to use regular expression, identify start position of desired 12 characters and extract it using sub string function.